# restructuring/partitioning a database table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a table which have the following structure, the columns are origin, destination, traveltime, and departure time. The primary key are a composite of origin, destination, and departure time. Is there any way to re-structure this so that there isn't too many duplication of origin and destination in the rows?

Comment: What do you mean by too many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of "too many duplication[s] of origin and destination" doesn't matter. It's only part of your unique key and it's necessary. If you really want to, you can create a separate table like this:

```
OriginDestinationKey
Origin
Destination
```

And then in the original table your PK would be

```
OriginDestinationKey
DepartureTime
```

But, you're still just going to have a bunch of duplicate OriginDestinationKeys. I wouldn't worry about it, as long as the structure/definition makes logical sense, having those duplicates isn't a huge deal. If you want to separate it so its easier to report off of, etc., then feel free to separate them out.

Comment: @aherlambang: Actually, what you were thinking of doesn't have anything to do with normalization. (And neither does Derek's "separate table".) He's right to say, "It's only part of your unique key and it's necessary."

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create 3 tables for that:

**Table locations**
location_id PK
location_name_short
location_name_long

example: 
1, NYC, New York
2, BOS, Boston

So first table has all possible origins and destinations

**Table travelPath**
travel_path_id PK
origin FK of locations table
destination FK of locations table

example:
1, 1, 2     (NYC to BOS)
2, 2, 1     (BOS to NYC)

So second table has all possible FROM - TO pairs

**Table departureTime**
tavel_path_id FK of travelPath table
departure time

Example: 
1, 10am
1, 5pm
2, 12am
2, 6pm

So third table can have all the departure times.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are designing a flight/train schedule. For each combination of orgin, destination, and departure times you may want to consider assigning a surrogate key. In the airline industry this could be considered the flight number for a particular airline.

Your current logical key needs to include departure time to ensure uniqueness for a primary key constraint (or unique index).

Comment: as far as I understand a surrogate key can only be used in a data warehousing scheme, in this case I am using mysql

Comment: Surrogate keys can be used in an OLTP or OLAP system. Your passenger table would consist of (Flight_SK, Customer_SK, Plane_SK, SeatAssignment). You would have both Customer and Plane entities defined with attributes unique to each along with a surrogate key.